# Can't install Sony Vaio VGN-NR180E video graphics drivers correctly

Tags: windows, drivers, display, sony-vaio

I can't install the video drivers on my dad's Sony Vaio VGN-NR180E (win XP home). I downloaded the video graphics drivers from [here](http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/swu-list.pl?mdl=VGNNR180E&SelectOS=7#div_pos_107) and it says that "video drivers have been installed succesfully"

I reboot but still it says in Device Manager that the drivers are "not installed" and I can't set the resolution above 1024x768px. It just won't show fullscreen – there's a thick black border.

Picture from the device manager (It's Swedish, so good luck):

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] and include your operating system. Maybe add some screenshots from the device manager.

Comment: Did you install both the Chipset driver and the Graphics Media Accelerator driver listed under the linked "video" driver section?

Comment: yes @techie007 i did

Comment: /cc @techie007 (@idiot you need to mention users with @ in order to have them receive a notification)

Comment: ok thx @slhck also i added a pic from device manager but its in swedish im sorry

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your antivirus is disabled when you're installing the drivers.
Second, make sure you're running the program as an administrator.

If that doesn't work:

Right click the item that isn't installing and select Update Driver.
Then tell it you want to choose what to install and find your vendor.  If the drivers did get installed to the system by your first attempt, you might be able to find your device in the list.

If not, you'll want to find a driver that you can point it to.  Do you know the chipset it's using, idiot?

Comment: +1 to question for me being able to add "idiot" to the end of my answer.

Comment: how can i find out chipset? @James